# Disable Fn Keys Dspf Rpgle

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I Have created a display file using Screen Design Aid that contains a subfile and a window that is used to pop up and add record to the subfile.
On the window I simply just want to have two control functions.

-Enter to add the record and close the window
-F3 to go back to previous subfile page.

I have a problem where my program seems to go on a infinite loop whenever I open the window and press any other Fn key besides those defined buttons.

See my Job in WRKACTJOB taking up a load of CPU

[image]

I would like to somehow disable input from all other keys to prevent users from getting this error and taking up system resources.

Here is my DDS code

```
A*%%TS  SD  20210608  183039  JAL         REL-V7R3M0  5770-WDS
     A*%%EC
     A                                      DSPSIZ(27 132 *DS4)
     A          R PRTWNDW
     A*%%TS  SD  20190630  072251  JAL         REL-V7R2M0  5770-WDS
     A                                      WINDOW(6 14 8 85)
     A            PRTMSG#       80   O  4  3
     A            PRTMSG2#      80   O  5  3
     A                                  1 31'Print Message Window'
     A          R ADDWNDW
     A*%%TS  SD  20210608  183039  JAL         REL-V7R3M0  5770-WDS
     A                                      CA03(03 'Previous')
     A                                      CA02(02 'Add/Update')
     A                                      WINDOW(2 12 22 105)
     A                                  2 36'ADD COST DISTRIBUTION RECORD'
     A                                  5  4'Supplier:'
     A                                  7  4'Brand:'
     A                                  9  4'Exp A/c:'
     A                                 11  4'Sub-Total:'
     A                                 14  4'ASB:'
     A                                 15  4'Supplier:'
     A                                 13  4'Cost Split'
     A                                 17  4'Check:'
     A            CSSUPC#        6A  B  5 18
     A            CSEXCD#        3A  B  9 18
     A            CSSTTL#        9Y 2B 11 18EDTCDE(2)
     A            CSASST#        3Y 0B 14 18EDTCDE(2)
     A            CSSPST#        3Y 0B 15 18EDTCDE(2)
     A            CSCHCK#        3A  B 17 18
     A            CSSUPN#       30A  O  5 32
     A            CSBRNM#       30A  O  7 32
     A            CSEXNM#       30A  O  9 32
     A            CSCHNM#       30A  O 17 32
     A            CSBRNO#        3A  B  7 18
     A            ADDMSG#       80A  O 19  4COLOR(WHT)
     A                                 21  4'F2 = Add/Update Record'
     A                                      COLOR(WHT)
     A                                 21 31'F12 = Previous'
     A                                      COLOR(WHT)
     A          R DUMMY                     ASSUME
     A                                      OVERLAY
     A                                  1  2' '
     A          R CMTDATA                   SFL
     A*%%TS  SD  20210608  152830  JAL         REL-V7R3M0  5770-WDS
     A            ACNAME    R        O  7  4REFFLD(APVENDR/ACNAME R50FILES/VAPV-
     A                                      END)
     A            BRBRDSC   R        O  7 37REFFLD(ANPBRNDR/BRBRDSC ANPLIB/ANPB-
     A                                      RND)
     A            CMEXCD    R        O  7 69REFFLD(ANPCSTCMTR/CMEXCD ANPTEST/AN-
     A                                      PCSTCMT)
     A            CMSTTL    R        O  7 92REFFLD(ANPCSTCMTR/CMSTTL ANPTEST/AN-
     A                                      PCSTCMT)
     A            CMBCSP    R        O  7109REFFLD(ANPCSTCMTR/CMBCSP ANPTEST/AN-
     A                                      PCSTCMT)
     A            CMSCSP    R        O  7117REFFLD(ANPCSTCMTR/CMSCSP ANPTEST/AN-
     A                                      PCSTCMT)
     A          R CMTCTL                    SFLCTL(CMTDATA)
     A*%%TS  SD  20210608  175516  JAL         REL-V7R3M0  5770-WDS
     A                                      CA12(12 'Previous')
     A                                      CA02(02 'Add')
     A                                      CA06(06 'Modify')
     A                                      CA07(07 'Delete')
     A                                      CA09(09 'Print')
     A                                      OVERLAY
     A  42                                  SFLDSP
     A  41                                  SFLDSPCTL
     A  40                                  SFLCLR
     A  45                                  SFLEND(*MORE)
     A                                      SFLSIZ(0100)
     A                                      SFLPAG(0015)
     A                                  1 56'PO Cost Distribution'
     A                                  3  4'PO Number:'
     A            FLD001        11A  O  3 16
     A                                  3 37'PO Sub-total:'
     A            FLD003         9Y 2O  3 52EDTCDE(2)
     A                                  3 69'Current Sub-total:'
     A            FLD004         9Y 2O  3 89EDTCDE(2)
     A                                  5  4'Supplier'
     A                                  5 37'Brand'
     A                                  5 69'Exp A/C'
     A                                  5 92'Sub-total'
     A                                  5109'BPI'
     A                                  5117'Supplier'
     A          R CMTFOOT
     A*%%TS  SD  20210608  173541  JAL         REL-V7R3M0  5770-WDS
     A                                      KEEP
     A                                 25  3'F2 = Add Record'
     A                                      COLOR(WHT)
     A                                 25 22'F6 = Modify Record'
     A                                      COLOR(WHT)
     A                                 25 44'F7 = Delete Record'
     A                                      COLOR(WHT)
     A                                 25 66'F9 = Print Supplier Copy'
     A                                      COLOR(WHT)
     A                                 25 94'F12 = Previous'
     A                                      COLOR(WHT)
```

And here is the RPGLE so far

```
     FANPPORCMT CF   E             WorkStn
     F                                     SFILE(CMTDATA:RRN#)
     FVAPVEND   IF A E           K Disk

     D FileInfo        DS
     D KeyPressed            369    369

     D EnterKey        C                   CONST(x'F1')
      ***
      /free

       // Internal Procedure Prototypes
       dcl-pr ClrVndSfile end-pr;
       dcl-pr LoadVndSfile end-pr;
       dcl-pr DspVndSfile end-pr;

       // Stand alone variables
       dcl-s RRN# packed(4);

       //Main Program--------------------------------//

       // Initialize
       *in40 = *off;
       *in41 = *off;
       *in42 = *off;
       *in45 = *off;

       // While F12 is not pressed display screen
       DoW *in12 = *off;

         ClrCmtSfile();
         LoadCmtSfile();
         DspCmtSfile();
         
         if *in02 = *on; 
            *in02 = *off; 
            
            exfmt addwndw; 
            
            dow *in03 = *off;
                
                if KeyPressed = EnterKey;
                    *in03 = *on; 
                    
                endif;
            
            enddo;
            
         endif; 

       EndDo;

       *Inlr = *On;

       //End Main**************************************//

       //Clear Subfile Procedure---------------//
       dcl-proc ClrCmtSfile;

         *in40 = *on;
         write cmtctl;
         *in40 = *off;
         RRN# = 0;

       end-proc;
       //*********************************************//

       //Load Subfile Procedure----------------//
       dcl-proc LoadCmtSfile;

         RRN# = RRN# + 1;
         acname = ' Supplier Testing';
         brbrdsc = 'Brand Testing';
         cmexcd = ' Expense testing';
         cmsttl = 1333330;
         cmbcsp = 50;
         cmscsp = 50;
         write cmtdata;

       end-proc;
       //*********************************************//

       //Display Subfile Procedure-------------//
       dcl-proc DspCmtSfile;

         *in41 = *on;
         *in42 = *on;
         write cmtfoot;
         exfmt cmtctl;
         *in41 = *off;
         *in42 = *off;

       end-proc;
       //*********************************************//

      /end-free
```

Comment: Is it truly an infinite loop, or are you just in a "bad keypress" state, in my emulator marked by a red X in the lower left?

Comment: @Mike well when I debugged it I kept going through the loop, and there is no red X, it says System instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this loop, if KeyPressed is not equal to EnterKey when the loop starts, *in03 will remain *off forever. I'm guessing you need another EXFMT inside the loop.

```
    dow *in03 = *off;
        
        if KeyPressed = EnterKey;
            *in03 = *on; 
            
        endif;
    
    enddo;
```

Comment: Inside the loop worked to help refresh the page on entry thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if *in02 = *on; //Window requested
  *in02 = *off; 
  dow *in03 = *off;
    exfmt addwndw;        //show window until enter or f3 are used
    if KeyPressed = EnterKey;
      *in03 = *on; 
    endif;
    if *in03 = *on;      //F3 used
      leave; 
    endif;
  enddo;
endif;
```

Comment: Don't mix K indicators with dds defined CF/CA indicators. In fact, just use the DDS defined indicators. The K indicators are harder to understand (there is at least one gap in the sequence, do you know where it is without looking) and they do not work all the time in modern RPG IV anyway.

Comment: Sure, what should replace if *inkc = *on?
Let me know and I'll change it :)

Comment: in this case where CA03(03) is used, *in03 is equivalent to *inkc.